# Find kernel of a homomorphism $f$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

I have $f: \mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2$ , $f$ is homomorphism such that $f(1,0) = (2,-1)$ and $f(0,1) = (-6,5)$. Find kernel of $f$. My progress:

$\ker(f)=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}^2: f(a,b)=(0,0) \}$

$f(a,b)=f(a,0)+f(0,b)=af(1,0)+bf(0,1)=a(2,-1)+b(-6,5)=(2a-6b,-a+5b) = (0,0)$

Now I get $2a-6b=-a+5b \Rightarrow b = 3/11a$. However, this seems to be wrong:

$b = 3/11a \Rightarrow (-4/11a,4/11a)=(0,0)$. If $a=11$,    $(−4/11a,4/11a)\neq (0,0)$.

So, what is wrong here?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Z}^2$?

Comment: You need both $2a-6b$ and $-a+5b$ to be equal to zero if $(a,b) \in \ker(f)$.

Comment: @DerekLuna The direct product of $\Bbb Z$ with itself. Probably as groups, seeing the tags.

Comment: @Gae. S. Thank you.

Comment: $(2a-6b,-a+5b) = (0,0)$ doesn't imply $2a-6b=-a+5b$ ("Now I get..."), but rather:

\begin{cases}
  2a-6b &= 0 \\
       -a+5b &= 0 \\ 
\end{cases}

whose only solution is $a=0$ *and* $b=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(a,b) = (0,0)\iff  (2a-6b, 5b-a) = (0,0)$$
$$\iff a = 3b, a = 5b$$
$$\iff a = b = 0$$

Hence, $\ker f = \{(0,0)\}$ and $f$ is injective.

Comment: How we get that $a=b=0$? Is that because $a$ has two values at the same time?

Comment: $3b=5b$ so $b = 0$ and $a = 0$ hence $a = b$

Comment: $a= 3b , a = 5b \implies 3b = 5b \implies 2b = 0 \implies b = 0$

Answer (score 1):

The homomorphism $f$ is injective because
$$\det f=\begin{vmatrix}2&-6\\-1&5\end{vmatrix}=4\ne 0.$$

More generally, over a commutative ring $R$, an endomorphism of a free $R$-module is injective if and only if $\det f$ is a non-zero divisor – which means nonzero if $R$ is an integral domain.